# It is possible to navigate with Resharper/Visual Studio to external sources located on a hard drive on some directory?

Tags: visual-studio, navigation, resharper

I have some open source components used in different projects. And some times it requires me to take a look at some classes sources from those components.
I do not want to add their sources as a project to my solution to see the source code.

Is there a way to tell Resharper/Visual Studio to open source code from particular location on a hard drive for such a components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If you have an assembly reference that also has a PDB with the correct path of the location of the source files, then using ReSharper (and I believe VS too) to navigate (e.g. F12/Go To Definition) would open up the source file in VS. Note that it will have reduced functionality as far as IntelliSense and tooltips go, as it's outside of the current solution and is not analyzed by the VS/R# tools. You will still be able to use F12 to jump to other solutions from that file.

The easiest way to make sure the PDB has the correct path is to build the components yourself, so that a PDB is created with local paths. If the PDB is missing or points at a non-existent path, R# will fall back to displaying class metadata (or the Object Browser, per your settings).